# How to display leaflet markers based on database table information?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet

I want to display as many leaflet markers as there are images related to the same project. Currently I am getting the number of images and the coordinates from MYSQL, saving that in a php variable and using its value on a JS variable.

```
// Contains Latitude for image 1
//$coord_pictures[0][0];
// Contains Longitude for image 1
//$coord_pictures[0][1];

// Contains Latitude for image 2
//$coord_pictures[1][0];
// Contains Longitude for image 2
//$coord_pictures[1][1];

// Marker name
var dynamicname = 'marker';
// Marker Latitude
var picture_lat = '<?php echo $coord_pictures[0][0];?>';
// Marker Longitude
var picture_long = '<?php echo $coord_pictures[0][1];?>';
// Number of pictures on table
var num_pictures = '<?php echo $num_pictures[0];?>';

// Function to create marker depending on the number of pictures
function Addmarker(markerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray; i++) {
        console.log(dynamicname + i);
        console.log(picture_lat);
        console.log(picture_long);

        this[dynamicname + i] = L.marker(
            [picture_lat, picture_long], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(map);
    }
}

Addmarker(num_pictures);
```

Output:

```
marker0
27.78233
-97.5608
marker01
28.78233
-96.5608
marker012
31.78233
-93.5608
```

I need help to use the 'i' value from the loop to access the different coordinates, and to use it on the marker name to create them dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oliver was right, my design was incorrect.

This is how I changed my design:
The PHP array is coded as a JSON representation and assigned to a JS array.

```
//Assign php generated json to JavaScript variable
var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($coord_pictures); ?>;

// Function to create marker depending on the number of pictures
function Addmarker(markerArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markerArray; i++) {
        this[dynamicname + i] = L.marker(
            [tempArray[i][0], tempArray[i][1]], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(map);
    }
}
```